# Unable to prevent Task Notifications from firing within Apex class

Tags: apex, trigger, email, notification

How do I prevent Tasks from sending notifications when they are programmatically reassigned to someone else via apex?

I am unable to prevent tasks from sending an email programmatically using the code below:

```
@future public static void updateTaskOwner(List<Id> taskIds) {
    Database.DMLOptions options = new Database.DMLOptions();
    options.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false;
    options.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false;
    options.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = false;
    List<Task> tasksToUpdate = new List<Task>();
    Set<Id> caseIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    List<Task> lVenueTasks = [SELECT Id, WhatId FROM Task WHERE Id IN : taskIds];

    for(Task vt : lVenueTasks){
        caseIdSet.add(vt.WhatId);
    }

    Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id IN: caseIdSet]);

    for (Task vt : lVenueTasks){
        Task t = new Task();
        Case caseList = caseMap.get(vt.WhatId);
        t.Id = vt.Id;
        t.OwnerId = caseList.OwnerId;
        t.Change_Ownership__c = false;
        tasksToUpdate.add(t);
    }
    Database.update(tasksToUpdate, options);
```

I found the snippet mentioned in this [article]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Database_EmailHeader.htm

However, even after adding that piece of code in the Task BeforeInsert trigger, the new owner still receives email notifications. The way the logic is setup is that when a Case is reassigned to another person, the case trigger would update all the associated tasks of that case to the new owner. This would cause the new owner to receive a lot of task notifications since that is enabled in Setup for individual Task association use. But since there are a lot of tasks associated with a certain case, the new owner would continue to be spammed by all of those reassigned tasks. It seems that no matter where I put the options.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false; code, emails would still be sent. Is there another way to prevent reassigned tasks from sending an email notification when done programmatically via apex without disabling the "Email me when someone assigns me a task" in Calendar & Reminders > Activity Reminders > Email Settings? I apologize if I sound vague or confusing and have updated the code snippet to include most of the contents of the TaskTriggerHelper apex file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: there's context missing here -- (1) `tasksToUpdate` is not declared; (2) what is the relationship between who calls the future, the future, and the task trigger? Please amend your post using [edit] - do not use comments